# Passing arbitrary data to a C++ callback that doesn't accept a "void* userarg"

Tags: c++, scope, callback, singleton, global-variables

### EDIT:

I have modified the example API so it better reflects the real API I am dealing with. The way the API get's the `message` argument passed to it is by user input so the `message` argument cannot be used to pass additional data.

---

I am dealing with a very frustrating API that uses callback routines that don't take "void* userarg" pointers.

Assuming the function that uses the callback routine as defined by the API expects a string argument (that will be assigned by user input), is there ANY possible way to get more data into my callback routine without using global variables?

**Here is a simplified example of what the API might look like:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ASSUME EVERYTHING IN THIS SECTION IS PART OF AN API AND IS NOT MY OWN CODE...
// I DO NOT HAVE THE SOURCE AND IT CANNOT BE MODIFIED

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(string message);

void call_callback(CALLBACK cb) {

    // Gets a message from user input
    string message = "hello"; // pretend this is user input
    cb(message);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int data = 42;

void callback_function(string message) {

    // I want to access "data" here WITHOUT it being global
    cout << message << ' ' << data << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    call_callback(&callback_function);
}
```

Typically an API that uses callbacks would also pass a "void* userarg" argument into the callback routine so you could pass additional data of any type, but that is not the case here.

This API is used extensively throughout our whole codebase and it is 100% necessary to pass a lot more data in every case where it is used. The current way we get more data in ****prepare to cringe**** is by storing practically all of our data in singletons so nearly everything is global and can be accessed from literally anywhere in the program.

This whole concept seems ***EVIL*** to me, but without a better API I can't figure out any better way to get the data into the callback. I have already contacted the vendor and asked that they fix their API to make it accept a "void* userarg" argument, but it doesn't look like it will be fixed anytime in the near future...

All I am hoping for is ANY better way of doing things than we are now.

Answer (score 1):

If it is really an `std::string` which is an argument to the callback (and not something else) and you really have access to the argument (as in your sample code which invokes `call_callback` with supplied string) you can put an entity-serialized pointer to your allocated object into `std::string` (which is allowed to have arbitrary data in it) and invoke `call_callback` with it.

One challenge here would be the fact that you'd than have to manually manage this pointer.

Comment: Good idea. But why not just use string hexadecimal representation of the pointer? Like `sprintf(buffer, "%p", pointer);`?

Comment: @BJovke why would you convert to string and than back? I see no reason for that. Just extra code and run-time costs.

Comment: It's actually a "const char*" in the real API but I figured "string" would just look cleaner in the example lol. This does seem like quite a hack though.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 first, MCVE would be better be matching real life, if you want meaningful answers. Second, with `const char*` you'd can check if anything there expects null-terminated string - if it does, you can go the text serialization route. And yes, it is indeed a hack, but I imagine, it's better than make all your data a singleton?

Comment: One more big monkey wrench to throw into the problem... The way the actual API is used, the "message" variable is passed at runtime as user input so it wouldn't be possible to use it as an address. :(

Comment: @tjwrona1992 like I said, MCVE is a king. Give the proper MCVE and you have a chance of getting a working answer. Make up something which has no connection with reality, and enjoy random answers.

Comment: You are right, but I tried to get as close as I could while making the problem simple enough to digest. With that added restriction I think the question pretty well describes the actual problem with the API. I can't really express how the entire API works because it is far to complicated to express in a stack overflow question.

Comment: I have modified the question to more clearly express how the real API I am dealing with works. The way it is presented now is much closer to the real API, but still simple enough to portray in a stack overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

My most straightforward idea would be to provide unique strings in place of the `void*` you would normally expect. You'd then have *one* map singleton that maps the strings to your callbacks.

So something like this:

```
class Dispatcher
{
public:
    // TODO: Thread safety etc.
    std::string makeCallback(std::function<void()> callback)
    {
        std::string uid = std::to_string(_index);
        _callbacks[uid] = std::move(callback);
        _index++;
        return uid;
    }

    void runCallback(std::string uid)
    {
        _callbacks[uid]();
    }

private:
    size_t _index = 0;
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> _callbacks;
};

void leaveAPI(std::string uid)
{
    getSingleton<Dispatcher>()->runCallback(uid);
}

void enterAPI(std::function<void()> userCallback)
{
    std::string uid = getSingleton<Dispatcher>()->makeCallback(userCallback);
    call_callback(leaveAPI, uid);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/KnrSKw)

You just count up a number every time you call the API and use its string version as the callback parameter. The class also maps each of those strings to the callback you wanted called. You could remove the map entries or do any number of performance optimizations, but this is the gist of it.

(This would work just as well with `const char*` if you figure out the ownership/lifetime questions that it opens.)

Comment: This won't work in my case. I have clarified the question to explain why.

Comment: If the library gives you no unique state from the callback to associate data with, you cannot get around storing the last callback target in a global variable (and you can never call it in parallel). You can contain that to a _single_ global variable, possibly hidden behind a singleton. But there is obviously no way around this global state if your assertions are true.

Answer (score -3):

You should really petition the writers of the API to use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of raw pointers to functions.

Then you can easily use e.g. [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to be able to call functions taking more arguments than the callback takes.

For example:

```
// The callback is a function taking one string argument, and return nothing
using CALLBACK = std::function<void(std::string)>;

// Do some processing and then call the callback function
void call_callback(CALLBACK cb, std::string message)
{
    // ...
    cb(message);
}

// Our callback takes a string *and* an integer argument
void callback_function(std::string message, int data)
{
    std::cout << message << ' ' << data << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int local_data = 42;

    // Using std::bind...
    using namespace std::placeholders;  // for _1, _2, _3...
    call_callback(std::bind(&callback_function, _1, local_data), "Foobar");

    // Using lambdas...
    call_callback([local_data](std::string message)
    {
        callback_function(message, local_data);
    }, "Foobar");
}
```

Using `std::function` also makes it easy to use member functions as callbacks as well, not only non-member functions (or `static` member functions).

---

However, if you *can't* modify the API, or the creator of it won't change it and it have to use C-style plain pointers to non-member functions, you can still solve it with lambdas, but you can't have any captures for the lambda:

```
call_callback([/*empty!*/](std::string message)
{
    // Call the function as defined in the previous snippet
    callback_function(message, 42);  // Pass the value directly
}, "Foobar");
```

Comment: From what i understood OP isn't designing an API but using one that is too restrictive, so i don't see how this fixes the issue

Comment: OP explicitly mentions that this code is not modifiable.

Comment: I am very inexperienced with using lambda expressions and I'm having a hard time getting the code to compile. Can you please elaborate and maybe provide a simple example that will compile and run?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Missed the message argument for the `call_callback` function. [Works fine in this example](https://ideone.com/96SRSS).

Comment: Okay, I got it to compile, but unfortunately I would need to use a capture because if I can't pass the data into the lambda expression itself then I can't pass it to the callback function either.